# Generates date between a date range

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need to generate the dates from start date and end date. For example, Start date is 11th March 2022 and the end date is 11th March 2023.

A screenshot of the end product is attached below.

[image]

I have been able to generate the dates from 11th March 2022 to 1st March 2023 using the below formula in power query

```
let 
StDt = [#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"],
AllDates = {Number.From([#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"])..Number.From([#"Vesting end date (each period)"])},

StofMonthDates = 
List.Distinct(List.Select(List.InsertRange(List.Transform(AllDates, each Date.StartOfMonth(Date.From(_))),0,{[#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"]}),each Number.From (_) >= Number.From(StDt)))
in
StofMonthDates
```

In the above query, Grant date means start date and Vesting end date means end date.

I have been able to get the below dates in power query.

[image]

I need to get the date as on the end date i.e., 11th March 2023 and not only the start of the month i.e., 1st March 2023. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To create a List of dates from start to end as you show in your example, as `startDate..Beginning_of_month_dates ..endDate`, you can

- Use List.Dates to create a list of all dates
- Extract the BOM dates
- Combine with start and end dates (or the first and last dates in the list)
- Remove duplicates in case your start date happens to be a BOM date

eg:

```
 = let 
  startDate = #date(2022,3,11),
  endDate = #date(2023,3,11),
  list = List.Dates(startDate, Duration.Days(endDate-startDate)+1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),

    BOM = List.Distinct({startDate} &  List.Select(list, each _ = Date.StartOfMonth(_)) & {endDate})
           
  in BOM,
```

[image]

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. I'm stuck in the duration part. i'm getting the following error "The name 'duration' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly."

Comment: @user17295743 you have a typo.  Copy/Paste here the part of your code that includes duration.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use List.Generate

```
let
    StartDate = #date(2022,3,11),
    EndDate = #date(2023,3,11),
    FirstDate = Date.AddDays(Date.EndOfMonth(StartDate),1),
    LastDate = Date.StartOfMonth(EndDate),
    ResultTemp = List.Generate(()=> [x=FirstDate], each [x] <=LastDate, each [x=Date.AddMonths([x],1)], each [x] ),
    Result = List.Distinct({StartDate} & ResultTemp & {EndDate})
in
    Result
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Add Column` section in Power Query,choose `Custom Column` and use following formula where `Number.From` transform your date column to its Corresponding number

`={ Number.From([Start_Date])..Number.From([End_Date]) }`

it generate numbers, then you should transform your numbers to date.